why does react-native 0.7.x require a minimum iOS version 12.4 instead of 12.0
When creating a React Native project using version 0.7.x, the minimum required iOS system version is 12.4. However, changing the minimum system version to 12.0 still allows the project to run normally. So why does it require a minimum system version of 12.4 instead of 12.0?

Why would someone have 12.0 version on one's iPhone?
